# .new and .create method for Rails nested resource(HABTM relationship)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two relationships namely, User and Branch wherein there is a many to many relationship between them(I used HABTM in their models) and they are joined by a table called branches_users.

An entry is created in the branches and in the join table when I use:

**User.find(1).branches.create({"branch_id" => 12312, "branch_name" => "sample"})**

but, when I use

**object = User.find(1).branches.new({"branch_id" => 12312, "branch_name"=> "sample"})**

and then use

**object.save**

The entry is created only in the branches table, so when I use **User.find(1).branches** the entry doesn't come up. I need a workaround for this, I need to use new instead of create since I have to do some manipulations before I save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example how to do it:

```
object = Branch.new({"branch_id" => 12312, "branch_name"=> "sample"})
object.users << User.find(1)
object.save
```

Before the `save` you can manipulate what ever you want. It will save the relationship in the correct way.

Comment: I have a problem! I have another relationship which is "products" which has a many to one relationship with Branch.The problem is the Branch_id is different from the id of branch itself(it has two ids). I need to refer to the Branch_id instead of id when I do Branch.products